# How to prepare windows PC to pricey roaming Internet connection?

Tags: windows, networking

I'm planning to use my WindowsXP-based pc to connect via GPRS/3G while in roaming. What I want is to check my e-mails & instant messages, which doesn't seem like a lot of traffic. What I want to avoid is other stuff on my PC (like antivirus, browser, etc.) wasting that pricey traffic on updates. Is there a way to configure my PC so only dedicated programs have Internet access?

Comment: This isn't a programming question: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Just don't run the other applications.  Your AV will only updated when there is an update and you should always accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an application which can monitor your network traffic. Usually the modem comes with such an app, but not all the time. "[NetLimiter](http://www.netlimiter.com/)" can monitor / log all the kilobytes.
(Besides that, for example, Opticon modem comes with an old software. However, you can download a new one from the manufacturer's site, and it brings data logging. So yeah..always install the latest.)

(And yes, have an up-to-date antivirus. Also, use "Opera Turbo" or something like that. IF possible.)

(Also, you can check Windows "[Performance](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749249.aspx)" tab. It displays every network traffic. You can use "[Proccess Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653)" too. Its got a "Show in tray" feature, where you can see the network activity. Useful, since you know that something eats your bandwidth.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, I would like to mention that I don't want to log/monitor connections, but rather prevent all of them unless explicitly authorized.

Comment: @user42629 - You are looking for a firewall. :)